# Bower install fails to find satisfying version, although there is a matching tag on GitHub

Tags: bower, bower-install

I am having problems installing bower dependencies on a Windows installation. Installation fails for me on Windows 7 x64, with git `2.6.4.windows.1`, node `v5.4.1`, npm `3.3.12`, bower `1.7.2`.

It works for a colleague on OSX (git `2.5.4`, node `v4.1.1`, npm `2.14.4`, bower `1.5.3`) and for a colleague on Windows 10 (git `2.5.0.windows.1`, node `v4.2.2`, npm `2.14.7`, bower `1.3.11`).

The error message I am getting basically tells mit that `bower-angular-translate` does not have a version tag that satisfies `2.8.1`, but the GitHub repository [*does* have a version 2.8.1](https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/releases/tag/2.8.1).
The failing packages are `angular-ui-router`, `angular-local-storage` and `angular-translate`.

I tried downgrading node to `0.10.x` and `4.x.x` and reinstalling bower, both did not work.

If anyone has experienced the same error message behavior with bower (on windows?) and has successfully solved it, [any pointers](https://xkcd.com/138/) would be greatly appreciated.

---

The error message after running `bower install`:

```
bower angular-translate#~2.8.1    ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~2.8.1

Additional error details:
No versions found in git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git
```

---

My `bower.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "My App Name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.4.7",
        "angular-animate": "1.4.7",
        "angular-aria": "1.4.7",
        "angular-cookies": "1.4.7",
        "angular-resource": "1.4.7",
        "angular-sanitize": "1.4.7",
        "angular-material": "0.11.2",
        "angular-ui-router": "0.2.5",
        "angular-local-storage": "0.2.x",
        "angular-translate": "~2.8.1"
    }
}
```

---

Just in case, my `package.json`:

```js
{
 "author": "My Name",
 "name": "My App Name",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "dependencies": {},
 "devDependencies": {
  "chai": "2.2.0",
  "gulp": "3.9.x",
  "gulp-angular-filesort": "1.1.1",
  "gulp-bower-files": "0.1.x",
  "gulp-clean": "0.2.x",
  "gulp-debug": "2.1.x",
  "gulp-concat": "2.2.x",
  "gulp-filter": "1.0.x",
  "gulp-inject": "0.4.x",
  "gulp-less": "1.2.3",
  "gulp-livereload": "1.3.x",
  "gulp-tsc": "0.10.x",
  "gulp-uglify": "1.2.x",
  "gulp-util": "2.2.x",
  "gulp-watch": "0.6.x",
  "karma-coverage": "~0.2.4",
  "karma-mocha": "~0.1.6",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
  "karma-sinon-chai": "~0.2.0",
  "merge-stream": "0.1.x",
  "mocha": "~1.20.1",
  "phantomjs": "^1.9.17",
  "q": "1.0.x",
  "run-sequence": "0.3.x"
 }
}
```

Comment: I just tried on my PC and works like a charm. Try to remove the bower cache (`rm -rf ~/.cache/bower` on Linux).

Try also to run it in another directory, like `/tmp` (I'm just wondering here...)

Comment: What terminal do you use? The Windows one or a replacement?

Comment: @rpadovani cleaning the cache via `bower cache clean` or deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\bower\cache` (the Windows variant of the path you provided) did not help. The error message hints that git *can not find a tag 2.8.1 when there is one`.

Comment: @Andra I am using git-bash included with [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.6.4.windows.1) (64bit build). Git, bower, npm are all reachable within my `PATH`.
Running via `cmd.exe` didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to change the git protocol from git to https by executing:  `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// ` ?

Comment: For me npm 3 has cause countless problems on windows. Try to downgrade npm to version 2 and see if that works for you as well. If downgrading doesn't work, you can remove completely node/npm/bower and then use an older node installer.

Comment: @MariusP. thanks for the recommendation, but as stated above, *I tried downgrading node to 0.10.x and 4.x.x and reinstalling bower, both did not work.*

Comment: @LeonAdler glad it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GitHub revoked my SSH keys, causing `git clone` to fail.

Since cloning repositories via `git clone --branch <tagname> https://<repo>` at the "missing" tag **worked**, I understood from the error message that bower was not able to find the tag.

Both my `bash` from msys-git and my `cmd.exe` were set up to use **Putty**'s plink.exe, while bower was trying to connect via **OpenSSH**. Putty was set up with the correct private key, OpenSSH was not.

The culprit here was GitHub, which removed my SSH public key from my profile, making `git clone` via SSH (which is the default for `bower install`) fail with a *`Permission denied (publickey).`*

[image: All your SSH keys are belong to us]

The combination of GitHub not sending me a notification email about this *and* the bower error message describing an entirely different error made error-tracing this a nightmare.

---

Kudos go to [Andra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3541845/andra) for the comment to use `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`. While not suitable as a permanent solution *(my company's git server enforces SSH, since it is superior to a simple user-password combination)*, it helped limit the problem to the SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the git protocol from ***git*** to ***https*** by executing:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```